# Details view finding a dropdown list box and binding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, detailsview

How can I find a control in a DetailsView....

I believe it needs to be done in the DataBound event and post the current value of the datasource for this field to the DDL.selectedvalue?

```
Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(DetailsView1.InsertItem, DropDownList).(FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
```

I am adding a DDL that I would like to present the current value of the field and be selectable in edit mode.

MARK UP ADDED:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'> </asp:Label>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  DataTextField='<%# Bind("Active") %>' >
           </asp:DropDownList>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  >
            </asp:DropDownList>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You're dynamically adding a DDL?

Comment: No dynamically populating it, from the datasource of the gridview. then in Edit mode I need to get the value back into the datasource. I have done this with Gridview, but cannot figure it out for Detailsview.

Comment: Did you try using a **templateField** and bind your DropDownList to the value of the DDL soure? Pls show us some **markup code** too!

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, a bit lost with the detailsview control.

Comment: try populating dropDownList2 with possible values for `Active` and afterwards use `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Active")>'` to select the current value within the DDL

Comment: I am having problems getting it populated with the Datasource values. bhow can I bind it with inline code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, all with inline code.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Active") %>' >
          <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: ?!?! Your question was about how to find a ddl inside a detailsview control, not how to bind data to it! Please be more specific next time